# Why isnt zurb Foundation 3 dropdown working on mobile?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Using Zurb Foundation 3 on a site.  The main navigation is basic setup with a few items having 'has-flyout'. below is sample code from my site.

```
<ul class="nav-bar">
  <li><a href="{site_url}">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Pay Bill</a></li>
  <li class="has-flyout">
<a href="#">Our Practice</a>
<ul class="flyout">
  <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-flyout">
<a href="#">Pediatrics</a>
<ul class="flyout">
  <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Nav 3</a></li>                      
</ul>
  </li>         
</ul>
```

it follows the same structure on the Foundation 3 docs.
bottom of page i am calling the js files needed:

```
<script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.foundation.navigation.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize JS Plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

not sure why it doesnt work, so any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried updating to version 4? it is mobile first and may clear this issue